# Will question DLCs merge with or override the list of questions in Who Wants to be a Millionaire?

Tags: wwtbam

In the *Who Wants To Be a Millionaire: Special Editions* game, players are given a chance to purchase (at least outside the US) DLC for the game which allow you to expand the question base of the game.

My question is: do the question banks of the game merge up or are they separated? As in, if I select the *Special Edition: Video Games DLC*, will I **only** see Video Games questions? Or will the questions merge up with the main game?